# How to convert a column data to a row in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, lamp, addressbook

This is basically for testing an address book php application. 
Here is the output I got from the SQL query. I want to convert this results to a row.

MySQL Query output

[image: SQL Query output]

Output looking for

[image]

Comment: Can you show the query?

Comment: select meta_relation.contact_id, contact_meta.id, contact_meta.meta_data, contact_meta.meta_value from contacts, contact_meta, meta_relation where contacts.id=meta_relation.owner_id and meta_relation.meta_id=contact_meta.id and contacts.id=1

Comment: It will work with a simple cursor and temp table

Comment: you have mentioned 3 tables in query, please mention that table structure in question as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Query

```
SELECT contact_id,
MAX(First_name) AS First_name,
MAX(Last_Name) AS Last_Name,
MAX(Primary_Email) AS Primary_Email,
MAX(Primary_phone) AS Primary_phone
FROM (
SELECT MIN(contact_id) as contact_id,
CASE WHEN meta_data='First_Name' THEN meta_value END AS First_Name,
CASE WHEN meta_data='Last_Name' THEN meta_value END AS Last_Name,
CASE WHEN meta_data='Primary_Email' THEN meta_value END AS Primary_Email,
CASE WHEN meta_data='Primary_phone' THEN meta_value END AS Primary_phone
FROM tbl
GROUP BY contact_id,meta_data,meta_value
) t
GROUP BY contact_id
```

### [Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47602/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try following query. Suppose **postmeta** is a table name

```
select a.contact_id,b.meta_value,c.meta_value,d.meta_value,e.meta_value
from postmeta a 
join postmeta b on (a.contact_id=b.contact_id and b.meta_date='First_Name')
join postmeta c on (a.contact_id=c.contact_id and c.meta_date='Last_Name')
join postmeta d on (a.contact_id=d.contact_id and d.meta_date='Primary_Email')
join postmeta e on (a.contact_id=e.contact_id and d.meta_date='Primary_Phone')
```